# Spark master taking ingress IP in docker swarm

Tags: apache-spark, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I am trying to create a spark cluster using docker swarm. I am having two machines both of them having `docker 1.12.3`.

I have created two images, the Dockerfile for the images are as follows:

**spark:master**

```
FROM java:v1
MAINTAINER bidyut
ARG SPARK_URL="http://d3kbcqa49mib13.cloudfront.net/spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz"
RUN apt-get update && \
   apt-get install -y curl && \
   cd /tmp && \
   curl -O ${SPARK_URL} && \
   tar -xzf spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz && \
   mv spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7 /opt/spark
ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
ENV SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark
ENV PATH=${PATH}:${SPARK_HOME}/bin
ENV PATH=${PATH}:${SPARK_HOME}/sbin  
COPY start-slave.sh /root/
CMD ["/root/start-master.sh"]

EXPOSE 4000-40000
```

The content of start-master.sh is as follows:

```
spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master
```

**spark:slave**

```
FROM java:v1
MAINTAINER bidyut
ARG SPARK_URL="http://d3kbcqa49mib13.cloudfront.net/spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz"
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y curl && \
    cd /tmp && \
    curl -O ${SPARK_URL} && \
    tar -xzf spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz && \
    mv spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7 /opt/spark`
ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
ENV SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark
ENV PATH=${PATH}:${SPARK_HOME}/bin
ENV PATH=${PATH}:${SPARK_HOME}/sbin
COPY start-slave.sh /root/
CMD ["/root/start-slave.sh"]
EXPOSE 4000-40000
```

Contents of `start-slave.sh`

```
spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://spark-master:7077
```

I am starting the service as:

```
docker service create --name spark-master --network my-network --publish 8080:8080 --publish 7077:7077 spark:master


docker service create --name spark-slave --network my-network --publish 8081:8081 spark:slave
```

After starting the logs I found out that the spark-master is listening on the interface provided by the `ingress network`

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
16/12/05 12:33:53 INFO Master: Started daemon with process name: 5@bfc74db9b5d5
16/12/05 12:33:54 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for TERM
16/12/05 12:33:54 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for HUP
16/12/05 12:33:54 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for INT
16/12/05 12:33:54 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/12/05 12:33:55 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: root
16/12/05 12:33:55 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: root
16/12/05 12:33:55 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
16/12/05 12:33:55 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
16/12/05 12:33:55 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(root); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(root); groups with modify permissions: Set()
16/12/05 12:33:55 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkMaster' on port 7077.
16/12/05 12:33:56 INFO Master: Starting Spark master at spark://10.255.0.6:7077
16/12/05 12:33:56 INFO Master: Running Spark version 2.0.2
16/12/05 12:33:56 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'MasterUI' on port 8080.
16/12/05 12:33:56 INFO MasterWebUI: Bound MasterWebUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://10.255.0.6:8080
16/12/05 12:33:56 INFO Utils: Successfully started service on port 6066.
16/12/05 12:33:56 INFO StandaloneRestServer: Started REST server for submitting applications on port 6066
16/12/05 12:33:57 INFO Master: I have been elected leader! New state: ALIVE
```

the log file of the `spark-slave` is as follows:

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
16/12/05 12:53:30 INFO Worker: Started daemon with process name: 5@f24dcc11b1f9
16/12/05 12:53:30 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for TERM
16/12/05 12:53:30 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for HUP
16/12/05 12:53:30 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for INT
16/12/05 12:53:31 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/12/05 12:53:31 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: root
16/12/05 12:53:31 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: root
16/12/05 12:53:31 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
16/12/05 12:53:31 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
16/12/05 12:53:31 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(root); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(root); groups with modify permissions: Set()
16/12/05 12:53:31 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkWorker' on port 58058.
16/12/05 12:53:32 INFO Worker: Starting Spark worker 10.255.0.8:58058 with 1 cores, 8.8 GB RAM
16/12/05 12:53:32 INFO Worker: Running Spark version 2.0.2
16/12/05 12:53:32 INFO Worker: Spark home: /opt/spark
16/12/05 12:53:32 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'WorkerUI' on port 8081.
16/12/05 12:53:32 INFO WorkerWebUI: Bound WorkerWebUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://10.255.0.8:8081
16/12/05 12:53:32 INFO Worker: Connecting to master spark-master:7077...
16/12/05 12:53:32 WARN Worker: Failed to connect to master spark-master:7077
tion.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
at
```

Can anybody help me out how to setup the spark cluster in `docker swarm` or point me out where I am doing the mistake.